# Slow startup on spring integration test. Cause? Can't disable RabbitMQ

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, integration-testing, spring-boot-test

I'm struggling in a performance problem on startup with my integration tests.

I'm trying to mock the messaging of the system. To do that, I basically use `@MockBean` on my gateway and use `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {RabbitAutoConfiguration.class})`. Example:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyApplication.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {RabbitAutoConfiguration.class})
public class MyTestIT {
```

These two configuration did the job very well, my tests run without problem and without any dependency with some external RabbitMQ.

But the startup time of the spring boot is very, very slow. It's about two minutes only in this part configuring `SimpleMessageListenerContainer`, `AmqpInboundChannelAdapter`, `EventDrivenConsumer`, `RabbitExchangeQueueProvisioner`, etc.

The log has some tips about what is the problem (I cut a lot of the messages, this is a sample):

```
2018-02-09 14:26:37.784  INFO [ms-project-name-service,,,] 13804 --- [           main] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'ms-project-name-service:test:-1.channel2-output' has 1 subscriber(s).

2018-02-09 14:26:54.110  INFO [ms-project-name-service,,,] 13804 --- [           main] c.s.b.r.p.RabbitExchangeQueueProvisioner : declaring queue for inbound: channel1-input.anonymous.417FtxKTTce7-_IR0tGuNA, bound to: channel1-input

2018-02-09 14:27:00.147  INFO [ms-project-name-service,,,] 13804 --- [           main] o.s.c.stream.binder.BinderErrorChannel   : Channel 'ms-project-name-service:test:-1.channel1-input.anonymous.417FtxKTTce7-_IR0tGuNA.errors' has 2 subscriber(s).

2018-02-09 14:27:09.186  INFO [ms-project-name-service,,,] 13804 --- [ce7-_IR0tGuNA-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer@4f0ea6f8: tags=[{}], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
```

The most strange is this one:

```
2018-02-09 14:58:42.783  WARN [ms-project-name-service,,,] 208 --- [geGeQP_9Li3Jg-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

This last one seems that he is still trying to connect on a local RabbitMQ.

There are a lot of these messages on the log. I can't understand why this is still happening even with RabbitMQAutoConfiguration disabled. It's a mystery too how the spring is subscribing in a channel if there is no RabbitMQ to connect.

Comment: Added a couple of tags in the hope that someone with experience using spring boot can help. There won't be much help from the programming side, as the problem could literally be anywhere in your code. What debugging have you done (I assume it's possible to debug startup of tests)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We had similar problem here and it was solved by changing the runner:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
```

to

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

They seems like the same on the documentation, but really kickoff our test performance.
Let me know if it work, I'm still looking into the documentation for more details.

Comment: This not make sense to me but... worked! In the Spring documentation they said that SpringRunner and SpringJUnit4ClassRunner is the same thing, but it's not. Thank you!

Comment: Cant believe it is the case, +1.

Comment: @MinjunYu see my complementary answer. The problem is not only that!

Answer (score 0):

After @Marco response, the problem was back after I removed the follow dependency of my pom.xml (for instance, it is my first dependency on `<dependencies/>`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-test-support</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

After return the dependency, the problem was soved. I changed to `SpringRunner.class` and the tests continued to be fast. I removed the dependency and the tests turned slow again...

I think it's a bug related with the Spring looking for the classpath to do the auto configuration.

By the way, some of the messages on log continues to happen, but they not take so long.

Other thing that help is use this configuration **for your tests**:

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitMqConfiguration {

    @Bean
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return new CachingConnectionFactory();
    }

}
```